# How do you split a JQuery command up

Tags: jquery

```
$('#something :input')
```

if I already have something as an object, ie:

```
var x = document.getElementById('something');
```

How do I do `:input` on that?

Something like this perhaps?

```
$(x).(':input')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
$('#something :input')
```

is

```
$('#something').find(':input')
```

Note the space between the two selectors means that `:input` is a descendant of `#something`.  This means the answer to your problem is

```
$(x).find(':input')

// Or, using selector context (which is less efficient but less chars)
$(':input', x)
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$(':input', x)
```

It searches for all `:input`s that are descendants of `x` (using `x` as its context).